# How to access Kubernetes API when using minkube?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

What is correct way to kubernetes cluster setup using minikube through the kubernetes api ?
At the moment, I can't find a port through which the kubernetes cluster can be accessed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Running `minikube start` will automatically configure `kubectl`.

You can run `minikube ip` to get the IP that your minikube is on. The API server runs on 8443 by default.

---

**Update**: To access the API server directly, you'll need to use the custom SSL certs that have been generated. by minikube. The client certificate and key are typically stored at: `~/.minikube/apiserver.crt` and `~/.minikube/apiserver.key`. You'll have to load them into your HTTPS client when you make requests.

If you're using `curl` use the `--cert` and the `--key` options to use the cert and key file. Check the [docs](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) for more details.

---

**Update2**: The client certificate and key are typically stored at: `~/.minikube/profiles/minikube` directory when you use the version >= `0.19` ([more informations](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/362d5fdc0a3dbee389b3d3f1034e8023e72bd3a7/CHANGELOG.md#version-0190---532017)). You probably need to set the `--insecure` options to the curl client because of the self-signed certificate.

Comment: Yes, but if you query the api-server, then it will through a "unauthorized request" error! So how overcome this error ?

Comment: ``kubectl`` throws this error, or are you trying to access the API server directly (curl types)?

Comment: No, I am not using kubectl, instead directly pinging the API endpoints using CURL

Comment: same problem here, if I run kubernetes without minikube it ask me basic credentials but for minikube it never asked credentials, it directly shows unauthorized msg

Answer (score 47):

The easiest way to access the Kubernetes API with when running minikube is to use

```
kubectl proxy --port=8080
```

You can then access the API with

```
curl http://localhost:8080/api/
```

This also allows you to browse the API in your browser.  Start minikube using

```
minikube start --extra-config=apiserver.Features.EnableSwaggerUI=true
```

then start `kubectl proxy`, and navigate to http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/ in your browser.

You *can* access the Kubernetes API with curl directly using

```
curl --cacert ~/.minikube/ca.crt --cert ~/.minikube/client.crt --key ~/.minikube/client.key https://`minikube ip`:8443/api/
```

but usually there is no advantage in doing so.  Common browsers are not happy with the certificates minikube generates, so if you want to access the API with your browser you need to use `kubectl proxy`.

Comment: For minikube v0.28.0 with k8s v1.10.0, the following worked to enable the swagger ui:  `minikube start --extra-config=apiserver.enable-swagger-ui=true`

Comment: Is it safe to make these publicly accessible/exposed?

Comment: If I'm running minikube on a GCP VM, I can't access the 8080 from out side. How can I do that, considering now port 8080 serves  HTTPS connections?

Comment: @RumeshMadhusanka You need to create a Firewall rule to open port 8080 for your VM. One way of doing this is navigating to https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list and creating the rule via the web console.

Answer (score 15):

I went through lots of answers, but lots of them are wrong.

Before we do, we need IP and token.

**How to get IP**: minikube ip
**How to generate Token**:

```
$export secret=kubectl get serviceaccount default -o json | jq -r '.secrets[].name'

$kubectl get secret $secret -o yaml | grep "token:" | awk {'print $2'} |  base64 -D > token
```

Note: base64 uses -D for mac, but -d for Linux.

Then, the correct command is:

```
#curl -v -k -H --cacert ~/.minikube/ca.crt -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat ~/YOUR_TOKEN)"  "https://{YOUR_IP}:8443/api/v1/pods"
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the most complete answer as it talks about the bearer token, which is required to access the API.

Comment: To avoid a dependency on `jq` when getting the secret name you can run instead `$export secret=$(kubectl get serviceaccount default -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}')`. Also there's no need for `grep` or `awk`, instead just run `kubectl get secret $secret -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 --decode`

Answer (score 2):

User [Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279627/sven-marnach) got me in the right direction however to get the correct server ip, crt and key location I ran `kubectl config view`.

```
$ kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /Users/user/.minikube/ca.crt
    server: https://127.0.0.1:32792
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: /Users/user/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt
    client-key: /Users/user/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key

$ curl --cacert ~/.minikube/ca.crt --cert ~/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt --key ~/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key https://127.0.0.1:32792/api/
{
  "kind": "APIVersions",
  "versions": [
    "v1"
  ],
  "serverAddressByClientCIDRs": [
    {
      "clientCIDR": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "serverAddress": "172.17.0.2:8443"
    }
  ]
}

 $ curl -s --cacert ~/.minikube/ca.crt --cert ~/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt --key ~/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key https://127.0.0.1:32792/api/v1/pods | jq .items[].metadata | jq '"\(.name), \(.namespace), \(.selfLink)"'
"shell-demo, default, /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/shell-demo"
"coredns-f9fd979d6-6b2nx, kube-system, /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/coredns-f9fd979d6-6b2nx"
"etcd-minikube, kube-system, /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/etcd-minikube"
"kube-apiserver-minikube, kube-system, /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-apiserver-minikube"
"kube-controller-manager-minikube, kube-system, /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-controller-manager-minikube"
"kube-proxy-bbck9, kube-system, /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-proxy-bbck9"
"kube-scheduler-minikube, kube-system, /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-scheduler-minikube"
"storage-provisioner, kube-system, /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/storage-provisioner"
```

Readers may also be interested in [link](http://www.ethernetresearch.com/kubernetes/accessing-kubernetes-api-server-through-rest-apis/).

Answer (score 1):

For **windows** users, here is an alternative to the much simpler `kubectl proxy` command:

1. mount your local host's `.minikube` folder using "`minikube mount [path-to-folder]:/host` . This way, you will be able to access the certificates from within the node.If you don't know the exact path to this folder, you can get it by looking at the `kubectl config view` response.
2. On a different command prompt, take note of the IP of your kube api server. this can be done running from your host ( windows ) `minikube ip`. Note that this is the virtual IP within your minikube container.
3. Start a bash within the minikube container.  `docker exec -it {your-container-id} bash`
4. Access to the folder you mounted on point 1). Now, simply curl to the Kubectl api server through its virtual ip from 2.):

   `curl https://{your-ip-from-2}:8443/api --key ./ca.key --cert ./ca.crt`
   Here we are passing the certs to be used. Notice how I am not using the proxy-client ones.

That's it. For learning purposes I think this is a more interesting method that directly proxying.

Answer (score 0):

These instructions worked for me https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#configuration-on-minikube

Needed to generate & upload pfx file, along with the other steps mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the above answers are right in their own sense.

I will  give my version of the answer:

1) What is the correct way to Kubernetes cluster setup using minikube through the Kubernetes API ?

Ans: I think this is pretty straight forward. Follow the installation steps mentions in the official k8s documentation for [minikube installation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/)

2) At the moment, I can't find a port through which the kubernetes cluster can be accessed.

Ans: This is too has a straight forward answer. You have to check your Kube config file. You can find it in your home directory `~/.kube/config`. View this file and it will have the details.

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /Users/username/.minikube/ca.crt
    server: https://192.168.64.2:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    namespace: default
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: /Users/username/.minikube/client.crt
    client-key: /Users/username/.minikube/client.key
```

The `server` detail mentioned here is your `api-server` endpoint to hit.

You can view this information using the `kubectl` command as well like this `kubectl config view`

Use below curl to hit the `api-server` using `curl`

```sh
curl https://192.168.64.2:8443/api/v1/pod --key /Users/sanjay/.minikube/client.key --cert /Users/sanjay/.minikube/client.crt --cacert /Users/sanjay/.minikube/ca.crt
```

Note: `replace the ip port and the path as per your config file in above command`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on xichen's and Seba's answers above, this is how to acquire a token from a terminal:

```
$ function get_token() { secret=$(kubectl get serviceaccount "$1" -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}') &&  kubectl get secret "$secret" -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 --decode; }
$ get_token target_account
```

I hope this would be useful for those who must use `kubectl` below 1.24 due to `minikube` issue with enabling ingress as stated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74542710/how-to-write-a-re-usable-bash-script-for-this/74543413).

Answer (score 0):

What did I need when I find this question:

```
minikube ssh
docker exec -it k8s_kube-apiserver_kube-apiserver-minikube_kube-system_cdcbce216c62c4407ac9a51ac013e7d7_8 kube-apiserver -h
```

or

```
docker exec -it -u root minikube /bin/bash
vi /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
```

Comment: I do not understand this post. The phrasing is like a question, but it has no "?" punctuation. If it is a question it still is strangely phrased, what do you mean by "when I find this question"? Then you provide two code fragments without any explanation. That does look like a solution you offer, with two options. But it all is so inconsistent. Could you confirm that you attempted to answer according to [answer]? In that case please [edit] to make that more obvious. Otherwise what remains is probably for you to delete this, if it is not meant as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the proxy:

```
kubectl proxy
```

Open a new tab and run with curl:

```
curl http://localhost:8001
```