# How to write a re-usable bash script for this?

Tags: bash, kubernetes

Due to `minikube` issues [13841](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/13841) and [13872](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/13872) (which I believe to be the same), I have to use `minikube` 1.23.2.  I try using `minikube start --kubernetes-version v...` with version 1.24+ but none works (not sure why).  Thus, I cannot use the convenient command `kubectl -n ... create token ...`.  Seba's answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720979/how-to-access-kubernetes-api-when-using-minkube) shows how to generate the token with this older `kubectl` version:

```
$ export secret=$(kubectl get serviceaccount default -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}')
$ kubectl get secret $secret -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 --decode
```

Apparently, the command is only good for service account `default`.  How can I rewrite that script so it can be used for other users as follows?

```
$ export my_script=....
$ my_script another_account
```

Comment: Why don't you use your own secret.yml in your project?

Comment: You make the `another_account` the first positional parameter in your script, i.e. you refer to it by `"$1"`.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. `export my_script` creates an environment variable, but does not in any way create a command named `my_script`.

Comment: @tripleee, that's what I am trying to get to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm guessing correctly what you are trying to ask,

```
#!/bin/sh
secret=$(kubectl get serviceaccount "${1-default}" -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}')
kubectl get secret "$secret" -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 --decode
```

which defaults to `serviceaccount default` but uses whatever you passed in as the first-command-line argument if you do.

If you save this as `ktoken`, `chmod +x` the file, and make sure the directory it's in is on your `PATH` (perhaps with a symlink), you can run

```
ktoken
```

to run it for the `default` account, and

```
ktoken otheraccount
```

to run it for `otheraccount`.

Tangentially, there is no need to `export` a variable unless you need subprocesses to have access to it.

Comment: How do I use this with `another_account`?  Putting it right before `-o`?  Can the second line be packaged so that I can call like: `get_token another_account`?

Comment: I updated the answer with a newbie-friendly instruction.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way to do it with `alias` and not having to save it into a file?

Comment: Aliases can't take arguments, but any code you put in a script could be a function instead if you prefer. Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter

Comment: I see!  Looks like this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

After checking out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212219/passing-parameters-to-a-bash-function), I can see one way to do this is creating a `get_token.sh` file with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
user_account=$1
function get_token() {
        secret=$(kubectl get serviceaccount "$1" -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}')
        kubectl get secret "$secret" -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 --decode
}

get_token $user_account
```

Then I can call from terminal:

```
$ bash get_token.sh another_account
```

Another way not involving a bash script file is to define the `get_token` function then use it:

```
$ function get_token() { secret=$(kubectl get serviceaccount "$1" -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}') &&  kubectl get secret "$secret" -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 --decode; }
$ get_token another_account
```

Not sure if there are other or better way of doing it.

Comment: Apart from the quoting error and the unnecessary adornments, this is basically identical to my answer.

Comment: They are indeed similar.